# Is it possible to find $f'(g(x))$ given $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$?

Tags: calculus

Is it possible to find $f'(g(x))$ given $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$? I think the question explains itself, but is it possible to do this using chain rule and the information given?

Comment: I think you want to find $(fg)'(x) $

Comment: Where, $f'(x) $ is given, it is obvious to find $f'(g(x)) $, whenever range($g$) in domain of $f'$

Comment: Of course, you can find $(f \circ g)'(x)$ if you know $f'(y)$ and $g'(x)$ for $y=g(x)$; this is just the chain rule. (That's not what you're asking for though.)

Comment: There is one special case, if we're told that $f'(x) \equiv c$ is constant.

Answer (score 4):

No. Knowing $g'(x)$ for all $x$ only tells you what $g(x)$ is up to some additive constant. So you cannot hope to recover the function $f' \circ g$.

For example, say $f'(x) = x$ and $g'(x) = 0$. Then all we know is that $g(x)$ is a constant function, and $f'(g(x))$ will be another constant function, equal to that constant; we can say nothing about its value.